# How can I get the Clone tool in texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting

My goal is to learn texture painting. I was watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZDMFkj8GqA), but got stuck, at 7:45, when they switch to the clone tool, in texture painting. Since I'm using a more recent version of Blender than the one on the tutorial, the button I'm looking for is not in the same place. So, where is it?

[image]

According to "someonewithpc" I need to give up trying to use the clone tool. I think there must be a way to get from where I am at in the process, to making a UV Map that I can wrap around the geometry using a combination of the front and side projections that I created on those sides.  I think that is what is shown in the answer given, but I am stuck.  How would you finish the project?

[image]

Obviously the side needs the most work, also the top and back.

Comment: Which version of Blender are you using?  Screen capture About Blender image or System Info text might help.

Comment: Release 2.76 is what I'm using.

Comment: I have posted this question to Joshua Alger from CGsidekick.com, who made the tutorial.  In the comments section on that page there was a mention of the Clone tool being moved elsewhere in the Tool Shelf.  I can't find it.  Hopefully Mr. Alger monitors his site.

Comment: I have edited your question.  If its not accurate please roll back the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a source texture to paint on the mesh.

Edit 12/22/2015.

Your question now shows more of your progress.

Historical Note.  At first I thought you were getting no texture paint results at all.  Thus I encouraged you to use an image source and the simpler brush first as step 1 for major results.  I estimated  the clone brush could wait a learning period. From you edits above your are ready to use the clone brush.

TexDraw brush step 1.  Clone brush step 2.  Then you decide and refine in step 3 and beyond.  Those are my suggestions.

Nooks and crannies that might not be visible in your reference photographs are suited to clone paint as your video shows.  Some people also have top of head photos.  Neck photos.

The interface of texture painting has changed since your video.  I was not really emphasizing this change in the very capable and complex texture painting.

Apologies for lack of clarity.

Here is an image below.

The sphere is using a texture in this first image.  This will be the target of your painting work.  Under the Tools pane on left you see the human figure texture as the source of Stencil painting with a regular [TexDraw] brush.  The Image editor windows show some results on the target texture.  In the 3D View / Texture paint window.  You see the large transparent brush stencil next to some finished painting work on the sphere placed in the distance. The arrangment is for discussion purposes.

[image]

A alternate image explanation.

[image]

Note the brush is a TexDraw brush.  Brush mapping is Stencil.  Do not use Clone Brush yet.  First feel comfortable with the TexDraw.   Clone Brush is a second step.

You may look at the history of this document to see the previous version.

Comment: Your answer has woken me up in the middle of the night with more questions. I don't see how it gets me closer to getting a good image to use on the head I have modeled.  I was able to create a UV Map of the head and then project the head and side view onto the front and side of the geometry.  Obviously that does not make a UV Map that can be re-wrapped around the head without errors.   I will submit them as another question since I can't find a way to add a photo that is more descriptive.  How do I edit my original question?

Comment: OK, I found the edit button.  How do I edit a comment?  This edition of my question was prompted by the above answer provided by @atomicbezierslinger.

Comment: I am constructing a new question about this project.  I find myself still having problems, though this did take me closer to the finish of this work.