# Texture painting on an existing material

Tags: materials, texture-painting

Is it possible to texture paint on a material that has been already assigned to an object?

Comment: Welcome to BSE.  Cycles Render or Blender Render? Static image or animated image?  A Blender screen capture of your situation would help to clarify.  Image such as PNG ....... or Blender/Cycles Material?

Comment: There are numerous ways to paint, combine images, and composite.  Please see ......... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43176/how-can-i-get-the-clone-tool-in-texture-painting/43267#43267 .  Please know that there are many ways to paint.  GIMP is something seen often here.  Please note that texture paint has a destination image. Image type PNG for example. Rather then the Cycles Render or Blender Render concept of [material].  I am trying to distinguish between a complex dynamic material and a saved image/texture/.png statically saved on disk.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is YES! And these are the steps you begin with:

1. Make sure to UV unwrap your model.
2. Apply a material, create and add an image texture.
3. Go to Texture Paint mode, and start painting directly on the model.

[image]

**IMPORTANT**

Remember to save the painted texture to a file or pack the image directly inside
your blend file, before you lose it!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response as well as your answer. My problem was that I knew that to texture paint you need to add an image in the UV editor that will be the canvass you paint on and with a color material already added to my object the canvass color became the new background color to paint on, well, just before I read your answer I discovered that when the box pops up when you are adding the New Image in the UV editor you can slide the alpha to zero and have a transparent canvass to paint on, so now I know of two ways to do it, thanks again for your help!

Comment: So your problem been solved? If yes then please mark the answered button ... or was your problem not solved by my answer?